# My computer randomly stops being able to connect to anything outside my local network (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I periodically become disconnected from the internet, in the middle of using the internet. (Windows 7 laptop)

- No external websites open
- Pinging anything outside of the local network results in the message
  `transmit failed. General failure`. This includes `ping 8.8.8.8`.
- Other computers on my network are fine.
- I can access my router's web admin via `192.168.11.1`. Pinging my
  router works fine.
- Pinging other addresses on `192.168.11.*` gives me the normal timeout
  failure message.

The only thing that works to fix it so far is a reset

Things I've tried:

- disable/enable wireless adapter
- ipconfig /flush and /renew
- netsh int ip reset

I'm stuck, not sure how to debug this, it doesn't happen frequently enough to make it easier to isolate what triggers it (once every 2 or 3 days)

Anyone know what's going on?